# mysqldump - How to get line break instead of LF in contents?

Tags: mysql, newline

mysqldump uses LF in field values, Is it possible to get line break instead of LF?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl1` VALUES (1, 2, "A\nB\nC");
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl1` VALUES (1, 2, "A 
B
C");
```

Comment: I have similar issue: lines are followed by extra ^M symbol. Currently I remove it manually with vim (replace with empty). But I fed up with it and I am looking for normal solution too...

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` dumps data as they were inserted.
If you want to transform data, you should do it right after the dumping.
You can use `sed` for this or whatever you prefer.

This converts <kbd>\n\r</kbd> to <kbd>\n</kbd> with `sed`:

```
mysqldump.exe -uuser -p mydb | sed "s/\\\r\\\n/\\\n/g"
```